# GWT buttons not responsive after RequestBuilder callback

Tags: gwt

GWT 2.5.1; using Eclipse 4.2 with GPE;
UI specified with UiBinder

The app puts up a splash screen containing a "Go" button. That button's click handler does various initialization, including hiding itself and showing three other buttons, images, and text; it also initiates a server request (XMLHttpRequest) via a RequestBuilder. The RequestBuilder callback uses the returned server data to draw a bar graph in a canvas element.

After I click the "Go" button the browser window looks as expected with all the visual elements mentioned above. But the three buttons are not responsive to clicks. Not only are their handlers not invoked, they don't show the slight visual indication of activation when the mouse is clicked on them. The browser is not frozen; e.g., if the window is resized the app's resize handler is called.

Based on logging: after the "Go" button handler returns the RequestBuilder callback executes; then "nothing happens" i.e., there are no more log outputs (unless I resize the window).

FWIW this is my first GWT endeavor.

Comment: Some code is needed. Without it, is just guessing ;)

Comment: @AndreaBoscolo I understand, but I don't know what code to provide.The ui.xml and the two java source files that might be relevant total about 1,500 lines. I suppose some educated guesswork is the best I can hope for: what kind of error might cause the problem?

Answer (score 0):

By experiment, I found a partial answer. The three non-responsive buttons are declared in the ui.xml file with {style.hidden} referring to a visibility:hidden attribute in my .css. In the java code I unhide these buttons with:

```
protected void showElement(Element e) {
  e.removeClassName(style.hidden());
  }
```

Evidently starting life as hidden and then shown this way is insufficient to activate the buttons. I am about to go off to research why this is so, but an answer to this "smaller" question is still welcome as long as I've not posted a comment indicating that I am less ignorant.

Answer (score 0):

(too long for a comment)

I have just discovered that the problem relates to the fact that I have buttons in the same position, of which only certain ones are supposed to be visible at a given time. In other words, the user would see at the same position on the page one of:

```
ButtonA ButtonB ButtonC
```

or

```
ButtonD ButtonE ButtonF
```

or

```
BigButtonG (as wide either of the preceding groups)
```

The problem is that regardless of visibility, whichever of the three above displays is declared last has (in effect) a higher z-index and is the only one that will be mouse-responsive. So I am just about to implement a solution of explicitly setting div z-indexes in the code which shows/hides button groups.

Comment: The solution indicated in my prior comment works fine. Whenever I show/hide a div containing a button group, I add/remove a style of z-index:9999 as well as removing/adding a style of visibility:hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Can you set the button's positions in your UiBinder file rather than in your Java code? Place them in a HorizontalPanel and they'll be spaced automatically.

And rather than interacting at the Element level to hide a button, instead call your button instance with setVisible(true); e.g., buttonA.setVisible(true)

Comment: As noted in the question, "UI specified with UiBinder." There wasn't a problem with spacing/layout. And setVisible uses the "display" element attribute, which in my case has the undesirable effect of affecting layout.

Comment: okay. I was misled by mis-reading one of your replies "I have just discovered that the problem relates to the fact that I have buttons in the same position, of which only certain ones are supposed to be visible at a given time".